# Estimating a vector from a rank-one symmetric matrix plus scaled identity

Tags: estimation, covariance, svd

I have a problem regarding estimating a $M\times 1$ vector from a given $M\times M$ symmetric matrix. The known matrix is a scaled identity matrix with a rank-one update. I have some idea how to start, but I don't know if this is the best way to go.

My model of the $M\times 1$ received vector is $\boldsymbol{y} = \boldsymbol{h}s + \boldsymbol{w}$, where $\boldsymbol{h}, \boldsymbol{w} \in \mathcal{C}^M$ are independent. $s$ is a complex scalar with zero mean and unit variance, also independent of $\boldsymbol{h}$ and $\boldsymbol{w}$. With this model, the covariance of $y$ is $\boldsymbol{Q}= \boldsymbol{h}\boldsymbol{h}^\text{H} + \sigma^2\boldsymbol{I}$ (assuming variance $\sigma^2$ and independence of the elements in $\boldsymbol{w}$).

I now want to estimate $\boldsymbol{h}$ from the ML estimate $\boldsymbol{S}$ of $\boldsymbol{Q}$, how do I do this? Is there a big difference if I make the assumption $\sigma^2 = 1$?

My first thought was to do it the following way, using SVD:

$\text{svd}(\boldsymbol{Q}) = \boldsymbol{V}(\sigma^2\boldsymbol{I} + \boldsymbol{D})\boldsymbol{V}^\text{H}$, where $\boldsymbol{V}$ is the matrix containing the eigenvectors of $\boldsymbol{h}\boldsymbol{h}^\text{H}$ and $\boldsymbol{D}$ is a diagonal matrix with one non-zero element on its diagonal. My idea was to (from the sampled version of this, i.e. $\text{svd}(\boldsymbol{S})$) take the average of the $M-1$ smallest elements on the diagonal of $\boldsymbol{D}$ to estimate $\sigma^2$ with $\hat{\sigma}^2 = \sum_{i = 2}^M d_i$, where $d_i$ is the $i$:th largest element on the diagonal of $\boldsymbol{D}$. I would then construct the matrix $R = S - \hat{\sigma}^2\boldsymbol{I}$ as my estimate of $\boldsymbol{h}\boldsymbol{h}^\text{H}$.

Now, I should be able to find an estimate of $\boldsymbol{h}$, but I don't really see it. I can take the SVD of $\boldsymbol{h}\boldsymbol{h}^\text{H}$ and find the eigenvector, say $\boldsymbol{v}_1$ corresponding to the larges singular value. Now I know that $\boldsymbol{h} = c\boldsymbol{v}_1$ for some complex constant $c$. Is there any way of determining this constant with the information I have?

Do you guys have any ideas or references?